# Django Model: root node appears as child in unsaved nodes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to model a tree structure within django. This is a reduced version of what I've got:

```
from django.db import models

class Node(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("Node", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def child_cnt(self):
        return self.node_set.count()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

So far so good. It works. But if I now start to create a hierarchy like that:

```
from ....models import Node
root = Node()
root.name = "ROOT"
root.parent = None
root.save()

n = Node()
print n.child_cnt()
>> 1
print n.node_set.all()
[<Node: ROOT>]
```

So what does the root node make as a child inside `n`? And how can I avoid that?

The problem disappears once I called `n.save()` but it is kind of nasty to see a node initialized with a `child_cnt` of 1 inside the admin site.

Comment: I've tested the code shown above, and child_cnt() shows 0, and node_set.all() returns []. For me it seems that there is some other code in the specified model, or in the app, that makes some changes to the model, which make it behave like this.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I forgot to add root.save() to the code snipped above. I corrected that now. On my machine, executing now behaves just like I said even for a new Django project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that sounds crazy, but I spent a few minutes trying to solve your problem and It didnt work in any attempt that I tried. 
Anyways, for the Tree ForeignKey, I find another solution Online, which is a entire library that takes care of this type of Key, https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt 
You can try it out, it might fit for you. I hate having to add a library for such a small thing, however I could not find anything better.

Also if you dont wanna import the entire lib, you can kind of bring just the TreeForeignKey to your code.

Comment: I had a look at the library and it seems to solve some other issues I had, so I will import it anyway. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some research - here are the results:

First, a note - when using ForeignKey with recursive relation, you should use 'self' instead of the class name:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Then - ForeignKey is OneToOne relation. It is not correct to enumerate a Node children while enumerating its parent nodes... 
Back on the question - when you call node_set.all() - that seems to be executed as Node.objects.all(), and that's why it shows items for a newly created Node instance(not saved in DB). In fact node.node_set cannot be used here to get the foreignkey for a Node. In order to have several children to a Node - you have to use ManyToManyField, e.g.:

```
children = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True)
```

and then calling it using:

```
node.children.all() # for all children
```

or

```
node.children.count()
```

**EDIT**:

A brief analysis:

```
class A(model):
    parent = ForeignKey(B)
```

then

```
a = A()
b = B()
b.parent_set.all()
```

will return all A's that has B as parent, or all A's that have parent_id = b.id. In your case, you actually have:

```
a = A()
b = A()
b.parent_set.all()
```

will return all A's that has b(==a) as parent, and in that case a.parent_id = b.id, but b.id is None (not saved), so you get all nodes(b) that has parent_id = None.

In fact this behavior is the same for non-recursive relations too. In the first example, having an A() saved with parent=None, and you'll get it in b.parent_set.all() for all non-saved B's.

Comment: First: Thanks for the "self" hint. I didn't know that.

Comment: Second: No node_set.all() does not get executed as objects.all(). Try adding a third node with parent=root and save it. You will still only get the root node when asking for the node_set.
Third: ForeignKey is a **many-to-one** relation. Anyway: I will have a look at the ManyToManyFields, but it feels odd, because there has to be only one parent for each node. So why not use a many to one relation?

Comment: Yep, not exactly like objects.all(), but more like objects.filter(pk=None). Agree for the many-to-one in general, but it is used strange here... counting the nodes for the parent of current node... Not impossible, but as it seems causes problems. My suggestion was to have children in nodes, instead of parent. After all it is children count that you seek here.

Comment: Agree to objects.filter(pk=None). Maybe I should file a bug for Django there. BTW: I need more functionality than just the child count, but it was the only thing giving me trouble. So I stripped away the rest. :)

Comment: It seem to be the same for non-recursive relations too - I've updated the answer. Makes sense to notify the Django developers..